# Stop Batch Process

Tags: apex, batch, iteration

Good day everyone,

I have created a batch process. Let say I have thousands of records to process. Now what i want is when there is an error encounter or some problem found in the data during the batch process, I want to stop or abort the batch process. Is it possible ? thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never tried it, but I don't see anything in the [System.abortJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_abortJob) documentation that says it doesn't work when called from the batchable so try:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Report errors here
        System.abortJob(bc.getJobId());
    }
}
```

I assume that making this call will also stop the `finish` method being called so you will have to do any error reporting immediately before the call.

Comment: I've tried it and i think its working . Thank you.